# Atlys Spartan 6 is not recognized by PC

Tags: fpga, spartan

I have a Digilent Atlys Spartan 6 FPGA board which i use to design a custom processor. When I connect the board to power and turn the power switch on, the power LED comes on but no other LED comes lighten up. And the board basically is not recognized by the PC. Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this problem i.e. there might be a mode selection in Atlys Spartan 6 board but I don't know anything about that. Please someone help me out on this phenomena. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Atlys ™ FPGA Board Reference Manual](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/atlys:atlys:atlys_rm.pdf) 1 Configuration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about configuring and using hardware. You may want to try asking on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).